# DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use Collection.count_documents instead

Tags: python, mongodb

```
def get_registered_user():
    users = collection_users.find({name:'john'}, {'regDate': regDate}).count()
    pprint.pprint("users：" + str(users))
```

While count() method in mongoDB python, I am getting warning as "DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use Collection.count_documents instead."

`Collection.count_documents()`   takes only one query. How can I pass above two queries simultaneously? Please help.

Comment: You cannot pass two queries simultaneously to any mongodb operation because doing that doesn't make sense. Your existing code is probably broken.

Comment: @D.SM is there any way to check above two condition to count final result

Comment: Pass them in the same dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `find()` method accepts two comma separated condition. But `count_documents()`  does not accept more than one condition.

For this purpose `$and` operator can be used. `$and` operator joins two or more queries with a logical AND and returns the documents that match all the conditions.

We can combine two condition as

```
def get_registered_user():
    criteria = { '$and' : [ {name:'john'},{'regDate': regDate} ] }
    users = collection_users.count_documents(criteria)
    pprint.pprint("users：" + str(users))
```